# Unable to connect to server on internal network

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, server

I have an Ubuntu server hosting a web server and various other things. If I were to    ping 192.168.1.5 from my laptop the connection just takes a while and times out. If I'm sitting right next to the router with an Ethernet cable the connection doesn't time out and it's almost instant. Same thing if I am not connected to my home network at all, it's almost instant and works perfectly. How can I make it work on a wireless connection?

Comment: make sure AP isolation is turned off in your wireless router settings.

Answer (score 1):

So I tried what mchid said and turned off AP Isolation in the router and now I can access my server without having to sit next to the router!!!